# concatenating columns from multiple unrelated 1-row resultsets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Assume I have these two queries in SQL Server 2014, both of which return one row from unrelated tables:

```
SELECT SUM(A) A, SUM(B) B FROM X
SELECT SUM(C) C, SUM(D) D FROM Y
```

I'd like to combine these queries into a single resultset that contains `A, B, C, D`.

What's a good way to do this within a single query, as opposed to multi-query solutions like selecting the results into and out of scalar variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two subqueries?

```
SELECT Q1.A, Q1.B, Q2.C, Q2.D
FROM (SELECT SUM(A) A, SUM(B) B FROM @X) Q1(A, B)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(C) C, SUM(D) D FROM @Y) Q2(C, D);
```

Comment: Or `CROSS JOIN` of course but hardly worth a separate answer.

Comment: @martin, yes but my fingers are used to typing cross apply, I almost never type cross join.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I tried to get the CROSS JOIN syntax to work with MySQL - no joy! Could you show me (us?) how that syntax would work with this problem?

Comment: @Vérace just replace `CROSS APPLY` with `CROSS JOIN`. (You will also  need to replace `Q1(A,B)` with `Q1` and `Q2(C,D)` with `Q2`. This is not needed in SQL-Server either but will give you error in MySQL.)

Comment: Seems that the "CROSS JOIN" is redundant - it can just be replaced with a comma, as per @Lennart 's answer to my other question. Thanks for your comment on my (now deleted!) answer - brain burp! Which would be more efficient - the CROSS JOIN or the SELECT NULL syntax of Lennart?

Comment: @Vérace Uisng a comma (`a , b` instead of `a CROSS JOIN b`) is just using old (pre-92) SQL syntax, before the introduction of `JOIN` syntax. The two queries are equivalent and perfectly valid - although the explicit `CROSS JOIN` is preferred these days.

Comment: Good answer. I also thought of the comma syntax and knew it would work  here but also that it was deprecated and should be avoided-- but I forgot that commas with no WHERE was a synonym for CROSS JOIN which works great for this case. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT MAX(A), MAX(B), MAX(C), MAX(D)
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(A) AS A, SUM(B) AS B, NULL AS C, NULL AS D FROM X
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS A, NULL AS B, SUM(C) AS C, SUM(D) AS D FROM Y
) AS T
```

You may have to cast NULL to whatever type A, B, C and D have

Comment: Brilliant - also has the advantage of running in MySQL - racking my brains last night as to how to get this to work. How would I do this using a CROSS JOIN in MySQL?

Comment: @Vérace, something like: `select A, B, C, D from ( SELECT SUM(A) as A, SUM(B) as B FROM X ) as U,  ( SELECT SUM(C) as C, SUM(D) as D FROM Y ) as V`should work I guess

Comment: Works with an explicit CROSS JOIN as well: `select A, B, C, D from ( SELECT SUM(A) as A, SUM(B) as B FROM X ) as U CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM(C) as C, SUM(D) as D FROM Y ) as V`

Comment: Indeed - as I found out, replacing CROSS JOIN with a comma works - you've done the inverse!:-)

Comment: I noticed the discussion on Mister Magoo's answer after I posted the comment :-)